# Using use statements inside and outside a PHP class to import traits

Tags: php, laravel, traits

Why should we use `use` statement to import a trait outside the class and then use it again inside the class ??!

Example (in Laravel User model) :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class User extends Authenticatable
{

    use SoftDeletes;
.
.
.
.
.

}
```

Why are traits treated in different way other than other classes where we just import namespace once outside the class and can use it directly ?!

Answer (score 2):

`use` keyword has different meaning in each context.

- Inside a class determinate the trait(s) that class use [See](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).
- In closures `use` is used to determine the vars to import inside the scope [See](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).
- Out of all, `use` import the namespace of a class to mapper a classname with that, is possible too set an alias with combination of `use` and `as` [See](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

Comment: btw, 3rd point ... they are only "aliases" .... `use Blah\Blah\Something` is `use Blah\Blah\Something as Something`

Answer (score 1):

Use of outside of class to include actual class using the namespace. Thus it is just included but not used in that class just yet.

If you really need to use that class inside the class then you need to use this inside the class.

You can omit the use outside the class by following way.

> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes ;

inside the class directly.

Comment: Why to use "SoftDeletes\SoftDeletes ;" in
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes\SoftDeletes ; although  SoftDeletes.php file is inside Eloquent directory directly ?!

Comment: Updated my answer. just pasted it twine.

Comment: Why are traits treated in different way other than other classes where we just import namespace once outside the class and can use it directly ?!

Answer (score 1):

Because the first `use` indicates **which** class to use that is already **required** by the autoloader. This helps prevent collision of classes with the same name.

E.g.

```
// same name but avoid collision by an alias
use App\Models\Request as RequestModel;
use Request;
```

The second use is bound to the `Trait` and indicates that it should be used in this class. You can (bad practice) have multiple classes defined in 1 file, that is why you need to show that you want to use the Trait on that specific class.

```
class A {
    use SomeTrait;
}

class B {
   /// not using Trait
}
```

**edit:** Maybe it's good to know there are 3 uses of the `use` keyword in PHP, all having a different meaning.

1. ```
   use App\Models\Product;
   ```

   Means: Use this Full Qualified Name when I type Product in the class(es) below.
2. ```
   class User
   {
       use SoftDeletes;
   ```

   Means: Load the [`Trait`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) *SoftDeletes* in this Class (inject some functions).
3. ```
   collect([])->map(function ($id) use ($product) {
    // function body
   });
   ```

   Means: use the variable `$product` inside the new [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) which has it's own scope. Without it you couldn't access the `$product` variable inside the function's body.

Comment: Why are traits treated in different way other than other classes where we just import namespace once outside the class and can use it directly ?!

Comment: Because you use those as a class somewhere in your code. The trait already works by just being present.

Comment: I mean that we can use a class from a different namespace once we import it in the newClass file outside the newClass. we don't need to import it again inside the newClass, but we need to import it twice(outside and inside newClass) with traits.. why ??

Comment: First time means specifying which class to use later on. The second time you really embed it in your class.

Comment: @onlineThomas - What if the use statement was moved to outside the class - e.g Laravel Http Kernel - Does this impact how the middlewares behave ?https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: @RajaKhoury Your example is an `use keyword` of the first type: declaring which class to use when they have the same name

Comment: @RowaydaKhayri I think classes are unique already when you import them, even there are many same class names, you must import them as alias by using 'as' keyword. And when you use those classes inside your current file, you write class name. In opposite, different traits may have same method names, and when you use trait, you only call their method name, instead of trait's name.